# Naming queues in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a web application that i want to make us of background processing with queues. After reading the docs, i cant seem to understand how to create a queue

This is how i understand it so far.

> Creating a job class to do the job

```
php artisan make:job Background
```

> Dispatch a  job to the queue

```
$job = (new ProcessPodcast($podcast))->onQueue('processing');

        dispatch($job);
```

`//This adds the job to the queue named processing`

> Listen to a given queue

```
php artisan queue:listen --memory=512 --queue=processing
```

Finally, what is the difference between

```
php artisan make:job SendReminderEmail --queued
```

and `php artisan make:job SendReminderEmail`

How do i create a queue with a name of my choosing?.

Answer (score 0):

The `-–queued` option will ensure that the class implements the ShouldQueue interface so when we dispatch a job to this class.